# Understanding Basic Python Google API Sample

Tags: python, google-api, blogger

I mentioned trying to get google java sample code working in one of my previous questions on StackOverflow, but abandoned trying to do that after realizing how deprecated the samples were. Since I dabbled in python a bit about 4 years ago, I decided that I would take a look at the Google Blogger API for Python.

While most of the API calls make sense, I cannot seem to get this sample to run correctly!

Here is the sample I am trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Simple command-line sample for Blogger.

Command-line application that retrieves the users blogs and posts.

Usage:
  $ python blogger.py

You can also get help on all the command-line flags the program understands
by running:

  $ python blogger.py --help

To get detailed log output run:

  $ python blogger.py --logging_level=DEBUG
"""
from __future__ import print_function

__author__ = 'jcgregorio@google.com (Joe Gregorio)'

import sys

from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient import sample_tools


def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'blogger', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger')

  try:

      users = service.users()

      # Retrieve this user's profile information
      thisuser = users.get(userId='self').execute()
      print('This user\'s display name is: %s' % thisuser['displayName'])

      blogs = service.blogs()

      # Retrieve the list of Blogs this user has write privileges on
      thisusersblogs = blogs.listByUser(userId='self').execute()
      for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
        print('The blog named \'%s\' is at: %s' % (blog['name'], blog['url']))

      posts = service.posts()

      # List the posts for each blog this user has
      for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
        print('The posts for %s:' % blog['name'])
        request = posts.list(blogId=blog['id'])
        while request != None:
          posts_doc = request.execute()
          if 'items' in posts_doc and not (posts_doc['items'] is None):
            for post in posts_doc['items']:
              print('  %s (%s)' % (post['title'], post['url']))
          request = posts.list_next(request, posts_doc)

  except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
      'the application to re-authorize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

I've run this sample in both PyCharm and the terminal, and while the code compiles and runs (which is more than I could say for the Java sample!) I cannot seem to follow where the sample is getting its information.

The sample requires a client_secrets.json file, which I populated with my client id and client secrets keys obtained from the Google API console, however, I don't see how the sample is supposed to get data on the current blogger user, as there doesn't seem to be an input to select a user, input an email address, or anything of the like. The service apparently obtains the current user, but it doesn't actually appear to do so.

client_secrets.json:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "[[INSERT CLIENT ID HERE]]",
    "client_secret": "[[INSERT CLIENT SECRET HERE]]",
    "redirect_uris": [],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

In fact, upon running this code, I receive the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /google-api-python-client-master/samples/blogger/blogger.py
This user's display name is: Unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google-api-python-client-master/samples/blogger/blogger.py", line 83, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/google-api-python-client-master/samples/blogger/blogger.py", line 62, in main
    for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
KeyError: 'items'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If someone could help me understand what I'm missing in my understanding of how this sample works, I would definitely appreciate it. My python is definitely rusty, but I'm hoping playing around with this sample code will help me in using it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code is self explanatory:

```
#libraries used to connect with googles api
from oauth2client import client
from googleapiclient import sample_tools


def main(argv):
  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'blogger', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger')
```

This above uses Oath2 Flow, you are redirected and need to authenticate (at least the first time you run this)

```
 try:

      users = service.users()    #googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object

      # Retrieve this user's profile information
      thisuser = users.get(userId='self').execute()
      print('This user\'s display name is: %s' % thisuser['displayName'])

      blogs = service.blogs()   #googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object

 # Retrieve the list of Blogs this user has write privileges on
      thisusersblogs = blogs.listByUser(userId='self').execute()  #retrieves all blogs from the user (you = self) 
      for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:    #for loop that iterates over a JSON (dictionary) to get key value 'items'
        print('The blog named \'%s\' is at: %s' % (blog['name'], blog['url']))

      posts = service.posts()    #googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object for posts

  # List the posts for each blog this user has
      for blog in thisusersblogs['items']:
        print('The posts for %s:' % blog['name'])  
        request = posts.list(blogId=blog['id'])     #uses #googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object for posts to get blog by id
        while request != None:
          posts_doc = request.execute()
          if 'items' in posts_doc and not (posts_doc['items'] is None):
            for post in posts_doc['items']:
              print('  %s (%s)' % (post['title'], post['url']))
          request = posts.list_next(request, posts_doc)

  except client.AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ('The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run'
      'the application to re-authorize')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

Running this returns  all your posts as follows:

```
This user's display name is: "something"
The blog named 'myTest' is at: http://BLOGNAME.blogspot.com/
The posts for myTest:
  POST NAME (http://BLOGNAME.blogspot.com/2016/06/postname.html)
```

Maybe you want to get started with basic requests, rather than code samples, to get familiar with the API?

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingABlog

start with the basics, Ex:

> Retrieving a blog
>
> You can retrieve information for a particular blog by sending an HTTP
>   GET request to the blog's URI. The URI for a blog has the following
>   format:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId

Depending on the pyton version you are using, you can import different libraries to do your requests, Ex.
from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId')
print r.text
```

this should retunr a JSON :

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#blog",
  "id": "2399953",
  "name": "Blogger Buzz",
  "description": "The Official Buzz from Blogger at Google",
  "published": "2007-04-23T22:17:29.261Z",
  "updated": "2011-08-02T06:01:15.941Z",
  "url": "http://buzz.blogger.com/",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953",
  "posts": {
    "totalItems": 494,
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts"
  },
  "pages": {
    "totalItems": 2,
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/pages"
  },
  "locale": {
    "language": "en",
    "country": "",
    "variant": ""
  }
}
```

you probably want to check https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/#Blogs

Comment: I updated my question to include more information on client_secrets, which doesn't seem to contain any reference to userIds. I will try out entering the userId in that portion of the code, thanks! The sample code comes from here: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/blogger. Their documentation wasn't straight-forward for me for some reason, so hopefully your suggestion works!

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the 'self' reference actually resulted in a broken http request. Which, by the way, thank you for that insight on the Http Requests! I just finished a project in school working with http requests, so that is helpful as well.  Perhaps I was just expecting too much out of this sample, as I gathered from the documentation that it already created http requests for me.

Comment: I just added the blogger API reference guide, which is what you really want to use

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the Blogger API is really what I want for what I'm trying to accomplish. My project involves taking a list of blog URLs and getting all the post data associated with those blogs.  It might be possible, but I'm not certain. I'd still really like to get the sample code to work, as it really is bothering me that I can't find a single working sample for Blogger APIs.

Comment: Looking a little closer at the blogger.py code, I noticed that service is actually constructed in the sample code.  Would that possibly be where the initial http request (getting a user's blog) is formed (behind the scenes, of course)? I might have a flaw in my understanding, but I thought that  all of the API methods mentioned in the reference guide were a way of encapsulating the requests.

Comment: view modified answer

Comment: Hmm, my problem seems to be that I am never taken to authentication to sign in, so there is no blog for it to read from. Perhaps it's my own inexperience with using a Python IDE? I'm currently using PyCharm. Also, thank you so much for sharing the requests library. I'm starting to think that I'm at the point where I'll get my own code working before I can get the Google sample working!

Comment: I tested the sample and created a dummy blog - on my first attempt it redirected me to login, afterwards, i was getting the above mentioned terminal info, using pycharm as well

Comment: If you can paste the terminal error message from pycharm into your post, it will be very much appreciated

Comment: I actually had posted the error already - it runs, but gets the user as 'unknown' since it never has me log in. It's near the bottom of my post. The only thing I could think that might be creating a problem is that I used homebrew to install Python.

Comment: just to be sure: you did replace the client id and secret, correct? and removed the brackets? And last thing... Try using Python 3.4 rather than 2.7 for this example, i dont think 2.7 supports ---from googleapiclient import sample_tools---

Comment: Correct and correct. Unfortunately, I just tried Python 3.4, and found that I'm having the same problem. The authentication window never comes up. I am using Mac OSX, not sure if that would be part of my issue. I honestly have no idea what's going on to keep the sample from working correctly.

Comment: Could my problem be in the type of Client ID credential I used? When registering my project in the OAuth Console, I selected 'Other' for my ClientID.

Comment: what kind of API key did you provide your app? did you provide Oauth Consent? did you setup a Service account key rather than an API key?

Comment: I was under the impression that if I had an OAuth 2.0 token (which I assumed was the client ID and client secret), then my project didn't need an API key (unless by API key you mean the OAuth 2 tokens). I created OAuth 2.0 client IDs credentials for this project, so it's not a Service Account key. My consent screen is set up with an email address and a project name.

Comment: While I still don't know why the Blogger Sample won't pull up the authentication consent window, I was able to accomplish some Get requests thanks to the request library you shared, and since I don't need authentication for my personal project anyway (just this sample), I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a basic working example for working with Google drive with Python client library.

**Recommendation for Python Client library**

I'll add another example for using google drive with python client library.

First of all I would Highly suggest using the [PyDrive](https://github.com/googleworkspace/PyDrive) library which makes the OAuth process much easier (Install with pip:  `pip install PyDrive`).

More details in [here](https://googleworkspace.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/quickstart.html).

---

**How to run a basic python code that interacts with Google drive?**

1 ) Go to APIs Console and make your own project.

2 ) Search for ‘Google Drive API’, select the entry, and click ‘Enable’.

3 ) Select ‘Credentials’ from the left menu, click ‘Create Credentials’, select ‘OAuth client ID’.

4 ) Now, the product name and consent screen need to be set -> click ‘Configure consent screen’ and follow the instructions. Once finished:

a. Select ‘Application type’ to be Web application.

b. Enter an appropriate name.

c. Input `http://localhost:8080` for `Authorized JavaScript origins`.

d. Input `http://localhost:8080/` for `Authorized redirect URIs`.

e. Click ‘Create’.

5 ) Click ‘Download JSON’ on the right side of Client ID to download `client_secret_<long ID>.json`. 
The downloaded file has all authentication information of your application. 
**Rename the file** to “client_secret**s**.json” and place it in your working directory.

---

**Basic code example**

Add your code and run it - for example basic code that returns all files in root directory:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


# Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

---

**If you receive 403 authorization error in the authentication process**

You will have to add your gmail account at least as a test user in order to proceed with the authentication flow:

[image]

---

**Additional Snapshots**

Image for steps 4.c and 4.d:

[image]

Image for step 5:

[image]